# If $f(x)g(x) = x$, then is it possible that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $f(0)=g(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

True/False: If $f(x)g(x) = x$, then it is possible that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $f(0)=g(0)=0$.  If true, explain.  If false, then give a counterexample.

Not even sure where to start, please help!

Comment: Do you know the product rule?

Comment: The question gives you a big hint. If $f$ and $g$ had derivatives what could you do to that equation?

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not possible:

By the product rule, we'd have

$$1 = (fg)'(0) = f(0) g'(0) + g(0) f'(0) = 0$$

Comment: Exactly what I expected.

Comment: Intuitively this is the observation that $f(x)g(x)$ vanishes to order at least two at $0$, whereas $h(x) = x$ only vanishes to order one at $0$.